# How to characterize the Borel sets of product between finite and uncountable space?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Consider the product space $Z=X\times Y$, where $X$ is a finite set with discrete topology and $Y$ is an uncountable compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual subspace topology. Denote with $\mathcal{B}(Z)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $Z$ and with $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. Is it true that:

For all $E\in\mathcal{B}(Z)$, there exists a subset $A\subseteq X$ and a collection of Borel sets $(F_x)_{x\in A}\in\mathcal{B}(Y)^A$ such that $E=\bigcup_{x\in A}(\{x\}\times F_x)$.

Comment: Why $A$? $F_x$ may be empty! You only have to show that $F_x := \{y \in Y \colon (x,y) \in E\} \in \cal{B}(Y)$.

Comment: You should not delete your question after getting a valid answer (such a deletion will also delete all the answers.) Does the answer below fully answer your question?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal X}\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal B}\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal C}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$Yes, this is true, even if you only assume that $X$ is at most countable. Moreover, let us actually show that the conjectured necessary condition for $E\in\B(Z)$ is also sufficient.

**Sufficiency:** Take any $x\in X$ and let
\begin{equation*}
    \B_x:=\{B\in\B(Y)\colon \{x\}\times B\in\B(Z)\}. 
\end{equation*}
Since the topology on $X$ is discrete, the set $\{x\}$ is open in $X$. So, by the definitions of the product topology and $\B(Z)$, the topology (say $T_Y$) over $Y$ is contained in $\B_x$. Also, it is easy to see that $\B_x$ is a $\si$-algebra over $Y$. It follows that $\B_x=\B(Y)$, for each $x\in X$.
Therefore and because $X$ is at most countable, if $E=\bigcup_{x\in A}(\{x\}\times F_x)$ for some $A\subseteq X$ and a family $(F_x)_{x\in A}\in\B(Y)^A$, then $E\in\B(Z)$.

**Necessity:** For any $x\in X$ and any $E\subseteq X\times Y$, let
\begin{equation*}
    E_x:=\{y\in Y\colon(x,y)\in E\}, 
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    E=\bigcup_{x\in X}(\{x\}\times E_x). 
\end{equation*}
We want to show that $E_x\in\B(Y)$ if $E\in\B(Z)$.
Let
\begin{equation*}
    \CC_x:=\{E\in\B(Z)\colon E_x\in\B(Y)\}. 
\end{equation*}

Suppose first that $E$ is open in $Z$. Take any $y\in E_x$, so that $(x,y)\in E$. Then there exist open subsets $V_x$ of $X$ and $V_y$ of $Y$ such that $(x,y)\in V_x\times V_y\subseteq E$, so that $\{x\}\times V_y\subseteq E$ and hence $V_y\subseteq E_x$. So, $E_x$ is open in $Y$, for each $E$ in the topology (say $T_Z$) over $Z$. So, $T_Z\subseteq\CC_x$. Also, it is easy to see that $\CC_x$ is a $\si$-algebra over $Z$. So, $\CC_x=\B(Z)$. So, $E_x\in\B(Y)$ for all $x\in X$ and $E\in\B(Z)$.

We conclude that $E\in\B(Z)$ if and only if
$E=\bigcup_{x\in A}(\{x\}\times F_x)$ for some $A\subseteq X$ and a family $(F_x)_{x\in A}\in\B(Y)^A$. $\quad\Box$

---

This description of $\B(Z)$ can be simplified as follows, with almost the same reasoning (cf. the [comment by Dieter Kadelka](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446609/how-to-characterize-the-borel-sets-of-product-between-finite-and-uncountable-spa/446615#comment1153679_446609)):

> $E\in\B(Z)$ if and only if
> $E=\bigcup_{x\in X}(\{x\}\times F_x)$ for a family $(F_x)_{x\in A}\in\B(Y)^X$.